# Numerically integrating an unevenly sampled function over area or volume

Tags: matlab, interpolation, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

From some finite element modeling software, I have the value of some function over a three-dimensional volume.  I would like to integrate the value of this function over the volume.  The trouble is that the data exported from the FEM software does not define the function over a regular grid, but instead over a collection of points (x,y,z) corresponding to the (uneven) mesh used by the FEM software.

**How can I accomplish this integration in Matlab?**

Comment: This depends on your data structure, but if you have a tetrahedral mesh and values given at the nodes, you are dealing with piecewise linear functions and only have to use the midpoint rule: For each tetrahedron compute the volume; compute the mean value of the tetrahedron's nodes, multiply those two for the integral of the single element and then sum them over the entire mesh.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html) to resample the function onto a regular grid:

```
% Suppose f gives values of the function at points (x,y,z)
% Here we will resample f onto a regular grid.

% Define the x, y, and z axis vectors for the new grid.
xg = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);
yg = linspace(min(y), max(y), 100);
zg = linspace(min(z), max(z), 100);

% Define the new grid
[Xg, Yg, Zg] = meshgrid(xg, yg, zg);

% Define an interpolator for the sampled function
F = TriScatteredInterp(x, y, z, f);
Fg = F(Xg, Yg, Zg);

% Now we have the function sampled on a regular grid and can use the
% traditional matlab techniques.

dx = xg(2) - xg(1);
dy = yg(2) - yg(1);
dz = zg(2) - zg(1);

my_integral = sum(sum(sum(Fg))) * dx*dy*dz;
```

But is there a better way?